# PostgreSQL declare unnamed row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I use the following select statment to retrive column data i need to proces:

```
SELECT c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name, c.column_default, c.data_type, c.udt_name,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
FROM information_schema.columns AS c
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
        ON c.table_name = kcu.table_name AND c.column_name = kcu.column_name
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage as ccu
        ON kcu.constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name
WHERE c.table_name = 'mytable'
```

Now i need to loop over the results from this select statement. I do that like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myfunction(tableName CHARACTER VARYING(18), rows NUMERIC(10))
RETURNS VOID AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  r ( table_schema varchar,
    table_name varchar,
    column_name varchar,
    column_default varchar,
    data_type varchar,
    udt_name varchar,
    foreign_table_name varchar,
    foreign_column_name varchar );
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name, c.column_default, c.data_type, c.udt_name,
                ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
                ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
            FROM information_schema.columns AS c
                LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
                    ON c.table_name = kcu.table_name AND c.column_name = kcu.column_name
                LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage as ccu
                    ON kcu.constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name
            WHERE c.table_name = tableName) LOOP

  -- My plpgsql

  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

As you can see i declare the row `r` by naming the column name and then the column type. Which does not work and I am given the following error message: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 615 Where: invalid type name "( table_schema varchar, table_name varchar, column_name varchar, column_default varchar, data_type varchar, udt_name varchar, foreign_table_name varchar, foreign_column_name varchar )"`

I also tried changing `varchar` to `information_schema.sql_identifier` and `information_schema.character_data` which are object types in the information_schema for the columns I am trying to read.

Am I declaring the row right and/or should I use a different method in looping over a select statement with multiple joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is simple if you use record

```
DECLARE
      r        record;
BEGIN
      FOR r IN select * from information_schema.columns
      LOOP
             ...

      END LOOP;
```

Comment: Wow that simple. Thanks for answering so quickly!